# NodeJs slowing down when process consuming big amount of memory

Tags: node.js, architecture

So, i have a `nodejs` process which is, when scaled consumes around 5-8gb of RAM. It is running within the docker container. launching with the arg `--max-old-space-size=12192` to increase the node process limit.

The memory consumption is OK, since i try to use a dedicated server (AMD EPYC CPU, 64GB memory) in place of the horizontal scaling with AWS or other cloud provider, because it is 10x cheaper in case if i can make it work on dedicated server (most of expenses for AWS/Google Cloud goes for network traffic, while the VDS have unlimited. The network side is already optimised with the use of GraphQL and minimising the amount of requests). The process itself processes huge amount of data in memory, in multithreaded fashion. There is no further significant optimisation from the side of the process code itself.

**When the process memory consumption reaches 3Gb+, it is significantly slowing down**. Docker is not limiting the container resources. The server itself is running on 5-10% load in terms of memory and CPU. SSD driver -> low drive load (low amount of I/O on the server side).

I guess re-writing the app to `golang` for example might improve it significantly, however that is really a lot of work.

**Anything can be done on the server setup / nodejs app side to prevent slowing down?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any kind of os-level throttling mechanism configured. What operating system are you using? If it is allowed, it would be useful to show part of the code that's doing the I/O.

Comment: throttling in terms of traffic limitation, or? if you mean on the side of the traffic - nope. the channel is also 1GB and sure not overloaded.

Comment: Maybe show us some code that handles the I/O if it is allowed.

Comment: the codebase is quite huge, lots of different usages, but in short - I/O is as light as possible. majority of data is stored in custom in-memory cache which is cleaning up periodically. disk I/O happens only at the app start and after each task finish (SQLite). That is also quite well optimised. the app runs about 7000 tasks/hour. I/O side is 99.99% not the bottleneck - maybe some limitations on `nodejs` side?

Comment: As memory fills up in nodejs, it spends more and more time doing garbage collection to reclaim objects eligible for garbage collection.  In extreme cases, your OS may actually be disk swapping to handle the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by horizontal scaling within a single VDS with `docker`.

As `jfriend00` noticed, the nature of the problem might be with the garbage collection - personally have no other guess.